# SMS send through Journey SMS Activity but has not been received

Tags: sms, sendsmsactivity, mobilestudio

As the title suggests I have a journey which sends an SMS message to a subscriber. The activity will Subscribe them to the KEYWORD used.

A test subscriber has gone through my journey but has not received the SMS message. Looking at the SMS message delivery reports I can see there are 2 "delivered" today which are my test records (2 different subscribers, but none received the SMS).

What could be the reason I have not received the SMS?

Both subscribers are OPTED IN to the keyword and their mobile number is prefixed with country code (447).

Comment: Which country are you attempting to reach?  447 isn't a valid country code per this list: https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

Comment: Sorry I mean it’s 44 which is the U.K. country code

Comment: How much time has passed since the event fired?  I have seen cases where I get my SMS up to 3 hours after the event fires - event when I received my push and email notifications from the same journey.

Comment: As it was sent to a colleague I can’t check now, but it was almost 2 hours when I last checked

Comment: Have you had success with the Journey for other phone numbers or were these the first two messages you attempted to send?  Can you confirm that you are using the correct phone number field in the Journey Settings?  Are you using the phone number from the SFMC Contact record or from the entry criteria.  If the SFMC Contact Record, have you confirmed that the number is correct?  If from the entry criteria, have you confirmed it is the correct field.  This has held me up in the past.

Comment: I've tried with a total of 4 numbers, 2 of them which have passed. I am using the correct mobile number field (the default one in Salesforce). The journey uses the Mobile Number from the Journey Data not the Contact Data.